# How does this statement of probability follow from $ Y \perp A | R $?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am reading through the [Fair ML Book](https://fairmlbook.org/) by Barocas et al. In chapter 4, they state that for all values $a,b$ that random variable $A$ can take on

$$P[Y = 1 | A = a, R = r] = P[Y = 1 | A = b, R = r]$$

is a consequence of sufficiency (or $Y \perp A | R$) when $Y \in \{0, 1\}$.

I'm trying to derive the equality from $Y \perp A | R$ and $Y \in \{0, 1\}$ by applying the definition of independence and trying to substitute. However that hasn't really lead anywhere as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried exactly? And what is independent of what here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The definition for independence of random variables is a universal statement.

---

For discrete random variables $Y,A,$ and $R$, we have that $Y\perp A\mid R$ means exactly that:

$$\forall y\forall x\forall z\quad\mathsf P(Y{=}y, A{=}x\mid R{=}z)=\mathsf P(Y{=}y\mid R{=}z)\,\mathsf P(A{=}x\mid R{=}z)$$

So by definition of conditional probability:

$$\forall y\forall x\forall z\quad\big(\mathsf P(A{=}x\mid R{=}z)\neq 0\to \mathsf P(Y{=}y\mid A{=}x, R{=}z)=\mathsf P(Y{=}y\mid R{=}z)\big)$$

Therefore for *arbitrary values*, $a,b,r$, as long as $\mathsf P(A{=}a\mid R{=}r)\neq 0$ and $\mathsf P(A{=}b\mid R{=}r)\neq 0$, we have:

$$\mathsf P(Y{=}1\mid A{=}a, R{=}r)=\mathsf P(Y{=}1\mid  R{=}r)
\\\text{and}\\ \mathsf P(Y{=}1\mid A{=}b, R{=}r)=\mathsf P(Y{=}1\mid R{=}r)$$

Therefore... *for all* $a, b,$ and $r$ (with the aforementioned restrictions)...

$$\mathsf P(Y{=}1\mid A{=}a, R{=}r)~=~\mathsf P(Y{=}1\mid A{=}b, R{=}r)$$

Comment: Thanks Graham! Maybe this is me not knowing the notation well enough, but I had interpreted $Y \perp A | R$ as a statement that $Y \perp (A | R)$ (so then independence would mean that $P(Y, A|R) = P(Y)P(A|R)$). But you seem to be saying that $Y \perp A|R$ actually means $(Y \perp A) | R$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes,  $Y\perp A\mid R$ is read as "$Y$ and $A$ are conditionally independent when given $R$".   @GalenHarrison